# Format die(); Message in PHP

Tags: php, html, formatting, message, die

Is there a way to style the output of php's `die();` message?

I want to add some HTML and CSS around the error message so that I could use it in a productive environment.

Comment: `die()` is just basically `echo ...; exit()` with a few extra minor semantics on it. output whatever formatting codes you want as part of the die message.

Comment: `die($str)` is basically `exit($str)`

Comment: You may also be able to use file_get_contents() to fetch content to output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the actual `die()` function, it will always print out exactly what text you pass it (which could be HTML, but might be awkward to use).

You could, however, simply make your own function that prints out an error message nicely and then calls `exit` - that way you don't have to repeat the HTML that you might otherwise pass to `die()` every time.

```
function die_nicely($msg) {
    echo <<<END
<div id="critical_error">$msg</div>
END;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why I hadn't this idea before. I will accept you answer when sackoverflow let me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if('1'=='1')
echo '<font color=red>';
die('Its true');
echo 'its false';
?>
```

---

```
   <?php
    if('1'=='1')
   {    
      echo '<font color=red>Itss true too.</font>';
      exit();
   }
    echo 'its false';
    ?>
```

---

Both above are working, just to clear your doubts. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add html to the string you are feeding to `die`, but even easier is just echoing out the html that you want before you call `die`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do like this,

```
die("<div>Error: ".mysql_error()."</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to change `die()` to its wrapper?